# What does "you can go about" means?

Tags: idioms

What does this mean?

...there are a number of ways that you can **go about** + ing
e.g.

1. there are a number of ways that **you can go about** analyzing
2. there are a number of ways that **you can go about** buying  there
3. are a number of ways that **you can go about** saving

Thank you.

Comment: Go about something: 
to approach the doing of something in a particular way. *How should I go about researching this topic? Would you tell me how to go about it?* http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+about

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I can not mark your answer as a solution for my question. Or even mark as valuable. I do not know why.

Comment: That's because @Josh61 submitted it as a comment instead of an answer. He should probably consider submitting it as an answer instead.

Comment: @plywoods - your question is considered as a General Reference one in this site that is something you could have answered looking *go about* in a dictionary.  Please Refer to our http://english.stackexchange.com/help and see how this site works. :))

Answer (score 1):

> [Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary Reference Book with ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=pqlRO2jdI2gC&pg=PA407&dq=%22go%20about%20something%22%20idiom&hl=en&sa=X&ei=C0EiVemBCYHmsAXJx4CwAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22go%20about%20something%22%20idiom&f=false)
> Cambridge University Press
>
> go about something **to begin to do something**

_

> [go about](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/go_1)
>
> 1 go about something
>
> **to start to do something:**
>
> *I want to learn German but I don't know the best way to go about it.*
>
> 2 go about doing something
>
> *he leaflet tells you how to go about making a will.*
>
> 2 go about something
>
> **to do something in the way that you usually do:**
>
> *The villagers were   going about their business  as usual.*
> *She went about her preparations in a quiet businesslike way.*